# View Animation does not work - ios Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, view

I have this piece of code that supposed to give a spring effect to mainView.

But I don't get the desired effect, I only get the Transition style applied to the ViewController via Storyboards.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.statusBarHidden = UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden
    UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .none)


    self.mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.getWidth/20, y:self.view.getHeight/6, width:self.view.getWidth/1.3 , height: self.view.getHeight/1.3))

    self.mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.mainView.center.x = self.view.center.x
    self.mainView.center.y = self.view.center.y

    self.mainView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 1.2) // initial view distorted scale so it has a starting point for the animation

    self.view.addSubview(self.mainView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
        self.mainView.transform = .identity // get back to original scale in an animated way
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Can you please help in getting the spring effect to mainView?

Thank you

Comment: Start animations in `viewDidAppear` not `viewDidLoad`. In `viewDidLoad` the view is not yet visible and it cannot animate.

Comment: just call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside your `UIView.animate` block

Comment: @Sulthan nice catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with animation you should understand view controller life circle. This is crucial in case that you describe becouse you should understand when and why to start animation.

**Firstly** read please about life circle in official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller).

Code, but try to understand why it now is working :

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mainView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addMainView()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       animateMainView()
    }

    func addMainView() {
        self.mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/20, y:self.view.frame.height/6, width:self.view.frame.width/1.3 , height: self.view.frame.height/1.3))

        self.mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.mainView.center.x = self.view.center.x
        self.mainView.center.y = self.view.center.y

        self.view.addSubview(self.mainView)
    }

    func animateMainView() {

        self.mainView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 1.2) // initial view distorted scale so it has a starting point for the animation

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
            self.mainView.transform = .identity // get back to original scale in an animated way
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Example of the animation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining me!

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution. the `addSubview` code should be in `viewDidLoad`, it shouldn't be in `viewDidAppear` because that would mean it won't appear immediately.

Comment: @Sulthan to be good UIKit citizen i even add super.viewDidAppear(animated). Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think you mean "life circle" or do you? ;)

Comment: @Rikh I mean view controller life circle )) but nice catch

Comment: It's never a good solution when someone tells you to read Apple's documentation. That's an hour of your time spent on stuff that might be good to get some in depth knowledge, but after that you might find that you still don't have an answer to your problem. Apple's documentation lacks examples most times too. So it's all theory, no real world application.