# Animating UIIMageView Alpha on view did load

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ios-animations

I am attempting to animate the background image of my `HomeController`.

I would like to fade the image in, as such I was hoping to animate it's `alpha` property.

I have found many answers on here around this, however many seem dated (obj c, iOS 3/4/5 etc) and following the recommended approach, I still cannot get this animation to work.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

I would like to animate `backgroundImage`. I have placed my animation code at the end of my `setupView` method.

It does not 'fade in' as I would like, essentially the alpha jumps straight to 0.7

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
    }

    private let backgroundImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "foggy").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
       image.alpha = 0
        image.isOpaque = false

        return image
    }()

    private let currentLocation: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Southampton, UK", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        button.contentMode = .center
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPressLocation), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    private let currentTemp: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("37°C", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 54, weight: .thin)
        button.contentMode = .center
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPressTemp), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

}

extension HomeController {

    @objc fileprivate func onPressLocation() -> Void {
        print("Location pressed.")
    }

    @objc fileprivate func onPressTemp() -> Void {
        self.currentTemp.setTitle("98°F", for: .normal)
    }

    fileprivate func setupView() -> Void {

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        // MARK: Background Image
        view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        backgroundImage.anchor(
            top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
            left: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
            bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
            right: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor,
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingLeft: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingRight: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        )

        // MARK: Current Location
        view.addSubview(currentLocation)
        currentLocation.anchor(
            top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
            left: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
            right: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor,
            paddingTop: 50,
            paddingLeft: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingRight: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 26,
            centerX: view.centerXAnchor
        )

        // MARK: Temp Button
        view.addSubview(currentTemp)
        currentTemp.anchor(
            top: currentLocation.bottomAnchor,
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingLeft: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            paddingRight: 0,
            width: 200,
            height: 70,
            centerX: view.centerXAnchor
        )

        // MARK: Animations
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, delay: 3, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.backgroundImage.alpha = 0.7
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? I think you shouldn't place any animation code in `viewDidLoad` since the view isn't even visible when `viewDidLoad` gets called.

Comment: Try calling `setupView` in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. It does no 'fade in' essentially the alpha jumps straight to 0.7

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is a better choice for getting things started

Comment: Ah yes, that has worked @iPeter - please consider answering the question so I may mark it as correct. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome @PetePete. Always ready to help. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View Animation does not work - ios Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407863/view-animation-does-not-work-ios-swift-3)

Comment: Btw, what about trying to call it *asynchronously* in `viewDidLoad`: `DispatchQueue.main.async { setupView() }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IBOutlets` does not get visible when `viewDidLoad` is called  so call your `setupView` method in `viewDidAppear` which is called after your view appeared on screen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code in **viewDidAppear** view life cycle method for any animation work ,because viewDidAppear method notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.Use below code for your solution.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
    //Call method like this 
      setupView()
   }
```